# How to access favorites in gnome-shell with keyboard?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

In Unity, I can press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> and so on to access favorites.

What is the key-shortcut in gnome-shell and where can i customize it?

Edit: I mean favorites in Activities Menu (after bringing mouse to top-left of the screen or pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>)

Answer (score 8):

There is en extension to do that. his name is Dash Hotkeys.
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/413/dash-hotkeys/

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to access your favorites in the dash using the keyboard. First press 'super' to open the overview, then press 'alt'+'control'+'tab' to pop up the accessibility switcher and focus on the Dash. Then you can navigate your favorite apps using the 'up' and 'down' keys, and launch them by hitting 'enter'. It's not very convinient, in my opinion, but it's an option.

---

I think it is much easier to simply hit 'Super' and type out the application name. But that's just me

Comment: You're right, it works, but typing app name is much simpler and faster.

Comment: I agree, typing the app name is faster for launching it. That's what I usually do. However, having keyboard access to the dash can be useful if you have the jump lists gnome extension installed. You can select one app and hit the context menu key to see your recently used files.

Comment: It is 'up' and 'down' of course if the launch bar is on the 'left' or on the 'right'. If like me the launch bar is down, then it is 'left' and 'right'.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, that isn't currently possible. You're welcome to open a wishlist bug for it though.

Comment: I don't know how to open a "whishlist bug" :).

Comment: Run ubuntu-bug gnome-shell to report the bug, then someone else can mark it as wishlist (since normal people don't have the ability to change the bug priority). It will also need to be reported at bugzilla.gnome.org since the GNOME developers are the ones that would actually need to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> makes numbers appear in the dock over the apps zero to nine. Maybe that helps a little. I try to navigate to the number I want after 0 but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Allow keyboard selection of windows and workspaces in overlay mode https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/10/windownavigator/